# How to return "Host is not resolvable" message after gethostbyname failure

Tags: python, tkinter

This might be a something simple here, but I'm still learning python.
Basically I'm trying to pull an IP address from a hostname, which works fine, but if the host does not resolve it errors. I have it now so that once it resolves the IP address it populates it to a text box, so what i'm trying to do here is if it fails to resolve... To put a message in that text box saying no host found or whatever. I get an error: "socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed" when it does not resolve.

This is the code i have:

```
def findip():
    host = hname.get() # Pulls host from text box1
    ip = gethostbyname(host)
    ipaddress.set(ip) #exports to text box2
    return
```

So what i don't know is the If command needed for the failure (if that makes any sense) it would be something like:

```
if "gethostbyname fails"
    ipaddress.set("Host does not resolve")
    else
    ipaddress.set(ip)
```

Comment: You need to use a `try/except` and catch `socket.gaierror`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try and catch the exception, this way:

```
def findip():
    host = hname.get()
    try:
        ip = gethostbyname(host)
    except socket.gaierror:
        ip = "Host does not resolve"

    ipaddress.set(ip)
```

Just make sure you have the `socket` module imported or it won't work, if you have no need for the `socket` module you can import the the exception only, so you need to do either of these:

```
import socket
import socket.gaierror
```

Comment: Thank you Dalvenjia, And Thank you Morgan Thrapp!

I managed to do the code but was still erroring because i didn't add the import on the socket giaerror - but it's all working now - thanks to you both!